# How to save data from a file but not in a variable or list in Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to read a file of about 5 Gbytes, and write a script in Python that has do to this:

```
cat file | awk -F '","'  '{if ($12 !="" ) print  $9,$10,$12}'| sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -100
```

9,10,12 being the parameters that I want from that file.

I can do it in Bash without problem, and in Python scripts with os.system and that command... But I need to write a Python script properly.

The problem is that I can't save data in any list or variable, because the script is going to run on a server can't use such an amount of RAM due to the size of the file.

I was thinking of writing the data to a file instead of a list, but I have not found a way to do it.

Comment: If you cannot use much memory, use intermediate files. It will take longer, but it will work. Why did you not achieved the way to do this? Which is the problem? Show us the code you have tried so we can pinpoint the issues.

Answer (score 1):

You may use at least a python [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) variable

That can optimize the storage of the triplets and the amount of times they appear.

Pseudo script:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    x = data[colums_that_you_want]
    xtoken = '_'.join(x)
    counter[xtoken] += 1


counter.most_common(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe it can helps if you combine this with the division of text proposed by other users.

You can save your data in a .txt file like this:

```
file = open("path/file.txt", "w") # This will create the file.
write = file.write(text_variable) # This will write the content of text_variable into your file.txt
file.close()
```

There is another way, which is using JSON:

```
import json
text = json.dumps(text_variable) # This will store the content of text_variable in a json format.
file = open("path/file.json", "w") # This will create the json file.
write = file.write(text) # This will write the content of text into your file.json
file.close()
```

Then, if you want to get the data of your JSON, just do this:

```
import json
file = open("path/file.json", "r") # This will open the json file in read mode.
jsontext = file.read()
text = json.loads(jsontext) # You will have in text the original data you had at the beginning.
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just for educational purposes, I would like to show that this line can be rewritten in a much more efficient way :

**original:**

```
$ cat file | awk -F '","'  '{if ($12 !="" ) print  $9,$10,$12}'| sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -100
```

**1. remove `cat`:**

There is hardly every need of the `cat` command.

```
$ awk -F '","' '{if ($12 !="" ) print  $9,$10,$12}' file | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -100
```

**2. improve `awk`:**

```
$ awk -F '","' '($12 !="" ){print $9,$10,$12}' file | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -100
```

**3. eliminate `sort -n | uniq -c`:** you can get rid of those two by using `awk` again. You store everything in an array, but that is essentially exactly what `sort` and `uniq` do too.

```
$ awk -F '","' '($12 !="" ){a[$9 OFS $10 OFS $12]++}
                END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}' file | sort -nr | head -100
```

**4. eliminate the last two pipes:** using GNU awk you can sort an array numerically using `PROCINFO`

```
$ awk -F '","' 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"}
                ($12 !="" ){a[$9 OFS $10 OFS $12]++}
                END{for(i in a) {j++; print a[i],i; if (j==100) exit} }' file
```